# why when an Android application is opened, an error message appears

Tags: android

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo
>   {com.MediaPlayer / com.MediaPlayer.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading
>   com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content: // media /
>   external / audio / media from pid = 1875, uid = 10141 requires
>   android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission () at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java
>   :706) at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity
>   (ActivityThread.java:2767) at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12
>   (ActivityThread.java) at android.app.ActivityThread $ H.handleMessage
>   (ActivityThread.java:1514) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage
>   (Handler.java:102) at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:163) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6205) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit $ MethodAndArgsCaller.run
>   (ZygoteInit.java:904) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main
>   (ZygoteInit.java:794) Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Denial
>   Permission: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri
>   content: // media / external / audio / media from pid = 1875, uid =
>   10141 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or
>   grantUriPermission () at android.os.Parcel.readException
>   (Parcel.java:1684) at
>   android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel
>   (DatabaseUtils.java:183) at
>   android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel
>   (DatabaseUtils.java:135) at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query
>   (ContentProviderNative.java:421) at
>   android.content.ContentResolver.query (ContentResolver.javaambat34) at
>   android.content.ContentResolver.query (ContentResolver.java:475) at
>   com.MediaPlayer.MainActivity.getSongList (MainActivity.java:21) at
>   com.MediaPlayer.MainActivity.onCreate (MainActivity.java:51) at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:6864) at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate
>   (Instrumentation.java:1119) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java
>   :659) ... 9 more

Comment: Give the android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in manifast

Answer (score 1):

You just need to give permission to access the external storage.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE">
```

Comment: Besides manifest, external storage will need to request runtime permission right?

Answer (score 1):

look for you AndroidManifeest.xml and kindly add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE">`

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mycompany.mymusik">
<uses-sdk 
    android:minSdkVersion="7" 
    android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
<uses-permission 
    android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission 
    android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission 
 android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission 
 android:name="android.perm.....